# json.loads не работает с JSONField

Tags: python, django, json, model

**Использую Базу данных MySql**

Модель БД

```
class all_product_db(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   mod = models.JSONField(encoder=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

чтобы получить данные поля JSONField
использую следующую функцию:

```
all_product_db.objects.get(id=12).mod
```

ответ получаю почему то с одинарными ковычками:

```
[{'name': 'Выбор пиццы', 'variation_id': [1, 2]}]
```

в БД записано поле с двойными ковычками формата

```
[{"name":"Выбор пиццы","variation_id":[1,2]}]
```

**Вопрос: Почему выдает поле с одинарными ковычками?**
и я не могу воспользоваться методом  json.loads так как при попытки выдает ошибку:

> TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list

Comment: В том что json.loads выдает ошибку  : 
TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list

Comment: тогда вопрос неверно сформулирован:-) Кавычки тут не причём. Предалагаю этот закрыть, как решённый, и открыть новый и правильный:-) Это "проблема ХУ" называется, кстати, - подмена вопроса.

Comment: Вопрос задан верно. В данном случае почему получаю данные с одинарными кавычками, хотя в поле запись вовсе с двойными

Comment: В примере в поле ответа моём вообще нет json. А ошибки нет, хоть и замена идёт. (Исправил ответ - не то сначал впечатал)

Comment: @Сергей Добавил больше информации по данному вопросу

Comment: А ответ на ваш второй вопрос вам сам интерпретатор дает: "JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray?  not list", а у вас - явный list (список) Кавычки и апострофы на это никак не влияют.

Comment: @Сергей если даже привожу строку в str то выдает другую ошибку json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Comment: С сериализатором поработать тогда надо, как понимаю. Сам не работал, но вот схожая проблема: https://russianblogs.com/article/57051409018/

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у вас и так python объект приходит из базы, его не нужно дополнительно как-то декодировать через `json.loads`. Просто берете полученный список и используете.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо сначала сериализовать данные с помощью метода json.dumps:

```
json = json.loads(json.dumps('[{"name":"Выбор пиццы","variation_id":[1,2]}]'))
```

Comment: Это бессмысленная операция. dumps от строки завернет вам строку еще раз в json. loads потом развернет правда, но в итоге вы получите ту же строку, что была в начале, т.к. loads и dumps обратные друг другу операции.

Comment: @insolor если вы считаете так, предложить метод решения

Comment: В комментарии к вопросу написал. Ничего не нужно делать. Если у вас такой способ работает, значит исходный объект вам уже подходит, потому что loads от результата dumps возвращает тот же самый объект, какой был исходно.

Answer (score 0):

В Python апострофы (') и кавычки (") эквивалентны. Поэтому и меняет.
json тут не при чём. Например,

```
X=[{"name":"Выбор пиццы","variation_id":[1,2]}]
print(X)
#даст результат: [{'name': 'Выбор пиццы', 'variation_id': [1, 2]}]
```